# igraph all_simple_paths() returns same number of paths with different vertices (R)

Tags: r, igraph

I have a network of ~8k vertices and ~10k edges. I want to collect the simple paths among each of the elements of a source set, to all the elements of a target set:

```
paths =lapply(sources, function(s) {
          all_simple_paths(graph, from = s, to = targets, mode="out") })
```

But I noticed that for most source vertices, I get either 0, 15808, or multiples of 15808 simple paths. The vertices are quite differently wired in the network, and I tried with different sets, so encountering always the same number or multiples looks suspicious to me (there are some exceptions, but very few).

Is it possible that I am hitting some memory limit, and therefore the function only returns a part of all the possible simple paths? How can I know, and how would I avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to add a [reprEx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/README.html#what-is-a-reprex) to your post using `igraph::sample_*` or sth. `all_simple_paths` crashes on my PC with even a small network that has a high density.

Comment: Thanks @lukeA. I didn't add any example exactly because I know it normally doesn't work for dense networks. I am running these in parallel on big memory nodes on a server, and still it takes some hours. I guess not so many people would be willing to reproduce this.   
The question is more for the ones who have a grasping on how the C function called by the R wrapper is, and how R itself might be limited in the memory it can use. I am not familiar with these concepts.